# Store data from multiple callbacks node.js javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I am using the knexjs ORM to retrieve data from my postgresql database. Is there a way I can more cleanly store data from multiple database requests? Currently I am doing it like this:

```
knex('user').where({
    approved: true
}).then(function(data) {
    context.approved = data;
    knex('user').where({
        unapproved: true
    }).then(function(data) {
        context.unapproved = data;
        console.log(context); //this is my main objective
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log('error: ' + error);
    });
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log('error: ' + error);
});
```

This could easily get REALLY messy if i need to make even more requests. Ideally, I'd like to do something like:

```
function a(callback) {

    knex('user').where({
        approved: true
    }).then(function(data) {
        //store this data somehow
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log('error: ' + error);
    });
};

function b(callback) {

    knex('user').where({
        unapproved: true
    }).then(function(data) {
        //storethis data somehow
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log('error: ' + error);
    });
};

function c(a, b) {
    //do an operation with the data returned from functions a and b
}
```

However, I'm not 100% sure how to implement this. Can someone help?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to look into promises. In your case you can use Promise.all() to execute all of your data calls asynchronously.

```
Promise.all([a, b]).then(function(value) { 
  console.log(value);
}, function(reason) {
  console.log(reason) 
});
```

Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all